# R - Party - How does random forest computation work?

Tags: r, classification, random-forest, party

I am running my first random forest algorithm using `cforest()` from the `party package`. Every time I run the cforest algorithm, RStudio crashes after sending the error message `"Error: cannot allocate vector of size 927 Kb"` which is a very small vector...

I tried to play with the controls, going very low in the parameters to get to the bottom of it but even with `controls = cforest_unbiased(ntree=2, mtry=3)` it still crashes with the same message.

Here the full line of code :

```
forest.result.balance$model.1$forest <- cforest(formula = quotation ~ minute + temp + humidity, data=undersamp.train, controls = cforest_unbiased(ntree=2, mtry=3))
```

For you to better understand what happens, my binary dependent variable takes values `0` and `1` and is 120k long and I have 3 continuous independent variables.
Moreover I kept track of the impact on memory usage during the computation and it reach 5Gb for RStudio before crashing.

So, do you know how I can fix this and also explain to me what is happening since running several `ctree` one after the other was ok but a single `cforest` made of two trees isn't.

**EDIT :**

I finded a way out by reducing the training sample by 50% but now I have the same problem with predict which in this case is extensive on memory use whereas it should only apply classification rules if I am correct. This is a complementary issue but does not answer the previous question as I don't think that reducing training sample should be the answer...

**EDIT 2 :**

Below complementary iformation on my data :

```
str(undersamp.train)
#
Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   68226 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ quotation: Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
     $ minute   : int  519 922 762 670 793 732 611 848 549 1233 ...
 $ weekday  : int  2 4 0 0 5 0 2 4 3 3 ...
     $ temp     : num  10.23 5.84 13.92 -7.48 6 ...
 $ humidity : num  74.8 95.7 81.8 89.1 98 ...
     $ pressure : num  1027 1023 1017 983 1020 ...
```

Comment: If you do `str(undersamp.train)` to see your variable types, are they all integers or numeric? I have run into the memory issue before when I've accidentally included a variable encoded as a factor and it has hundreds or thousands of levels.

Comment: This is very likely the case, I would check the class of your variables! It is likely that the minute variable might be a factor. Also, everything looks ok in your code, but we cannot help unless we get a sample of your data or you provide answers to these questions.

Comment: I added the required info above. All independant variables are either `int` or `num`. Other ideas ?

Comment: What about using a different RF? Party is not optimised for larger datasets. [Here is a list](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/10001/optimized-implementations-of-the-random-forest-algorithm/10028#10028).

Comment: Thanks, I will try them. I planned to try RandomForest and Bigrf but it seems that there are better packages out there.
I wanted to keep the party package to compare the prediction performance with the tree models I have made with the Party package.

Also, if anyone has the answer to why it is not efficient for building the forest and also (which surprise me) for the prediction on test data, you are welcome :)